# How to connect my base machine to the VM on hyper-v with virtual switch

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v, switch

Here I have a problem. I have two VM on hyper-v one is windows server and the other is RHEL. I want my base machine to connect with the virtual machines. On my base machine I don't have a network cable plugged in also I don't have a WLAN. I tried creating a external switch and configured IP settings but cannot ping them, I guess just because I don't have the network cable plugged into the NIC card. Help me find a way to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a internal virtual switch.

[image: Internal virtual switch]